# Can Tabhost be implemented in a activity extended as a Fragment implementing TabListner?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a activity extended as Fragment and implements TabListner. Can I implement TabHost(not Fragment TabHost) in that activity. Because when I tried I cannot find the tabhost in findViewById.

UserProfile.java

```
public class UserProfile extends Fragment implements TabListener{


    private static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    Map<String, AttributeValue> map = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    TabHost mTabHost;

    ImageView profilepic;
    String userId = new PassValues().getUserId();
    ArrayList<UserDetailsBean> ar = new ArrayList<UserDetailsBean>();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_profile,
                container, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        //profilepic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);


        /*mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent1);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            UserDetailsActivity.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
            UserJoinedGroupsActivity.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
            UserPostedDiscussionActivity.class, null);*/






        AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<UserDetailsBean>> async = new GetUserDetailsDataSource()
                .execute(userId);
        try {
            ar = async.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++)
            name.setText(ar.get(i).getFirstname() + " "
                    + ar.get(i).getLastname());

        profilepic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            System.out.println(selectedImage);
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            System.out
                    .println((new PassValues().getUserId() + new LoginSharePreferences()
                            .getEmailId(getActivity())));
            System.out.println(ar.get(0).getProfilePicPath());
            AsyncTask<String, Void, Map<String, AttributeValue>> async = new InterestGroupsListDataSource(
                    userId, picturePath,
                    new LoginSharePreferences().getEmailId(getActivity()), ar
                            .get(0).getProfilePicPath(), "profile").execute();
            try {
                map = async.get();
                System.out.println(map.get("Profile Image Path").getS());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // profilepic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(map.get("Profile Image Path").getS()));
            profilepic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ar.get(0)
                    .getProfilePicPath()));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

activity_user_profile.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".UserProfile" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_shape_google" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:text="Anubhav Bhardwaj"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" >
            </TabWidget>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your activity as TabActivity to get the tabhost method in your program. If your activity is extended as FragmentActivity you can Implement any listener class but you can get the Tabhost in that activity.

Just change your activity as

```
    Public class *youactivity* extends TabActivity implements TabListener{
               *Your code*
}


<TabHost
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I have just posted the code. Can you please see it?

Comment: just replace the id for your tabhost as  `<TabHost
        **android:id="@+id/tabhost"**
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >`

you can get the tabhost in findviewbyid...!

Comment: not working. Giving an error start or end with attributes ">" or "/>"

Comment: See the changes made and and provide with the full log window error to help more